# Is this proof of transitive property of implication correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is this proof correct? I would like to prove that from $A \implies B$ and $B \implies C$ follows $A \implies C$.

Assume $A$ holds. I know that $A$ and $A \implies B$ hold, thus $B$ holds. I know that $B$ and $B \implies C$ hold, thus $C$ holds.

Assuming $A$, I showed $C$. Thus $A \implies C$ holds.

Seems almost too simple. Is this a correct way to proceed?

Comment: Correct........